# MySQL Select row using "only if" condition

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to write a query to select rows such that the condition is met strictly. I think the best way to show what I'm trying to do is with an example.

Suppose I have the following table

```
+------------+
| A_Table    |
+----+-------+
| id | value |
+----+-------+
|  1 |     1 |
|  2 |     1 |
|  2 |     2 |
|  3 |     1 |
|  3 |     2 |
|  3 |     5 |
+----+-------+
```

What I would like is a query that returns the id that matches only the given values. For example say I want the id with values strictly in  (1,2), id=2 is the only one that satisfies this. Even though id=3 has values 1 and 2 it doesn't strictly have only those values (as well as id=1).

Here is the query that I came up with is

```
select id
from A_Table a
where value in (1,2)
and not exists (
  select b.id 
  from A_Table b
  where value not in (1,2)
  and b.id = a.id
);
```

But this returns both 1 and 2, because the in operator is satisfied with just the value 1 for id 1. I'm not sure how to enforce the "strict" part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this using aggregation:

```
select a.id
from a_table a
group by a.id
having sum(a.value = 1) > 0 and         -- id has value = 1
       sum(a.value = 2) > 0 and         -- id has value = 2
       sum(a.value not in (1, 2)) = 0;  -- id has nothing else
```

Comment: Hey @Gordon, great stuff! I have yet to learn about this way of using column comparisons inside having clause. Although wouldn't you rather use count instead of sum incase negative values are allowed?

Comment: It is summing over a boolean expression so only 1s or 0s will be summed, thus no negatives. (edit: I just tried it with count, and it didn't work).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group by` like

```
select id
from tbl1
group by id
having count(distinct value) = 2;
```

Here is an Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b1b23/1

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:

```
select id
from A_table as a
where exists (
    select 1
    from A_Table
    where value in (1, 2)
    and id = a.id
    )
and not exists (
    select 1
    from A_Table
    where value not in (1, 2)
    and id = a.id
    )
group by id
```